# CET vs Europe/Oslo timezone naming

Tags: terminology

Both `CET` and eg. `Europe/Oslo` is called a `Timezone`. But the city of Oslo is experiencing `CEST` in the summer-time (as many others).

What is the correct way to refeer to the timezone identifier that `Europe/Oslo` is?

Will this be a good wording?;

- The current timezone is `CET`
- The current timezone identifier is `Europe/Oslo`

Comment: Strictly speaking, CET is a *time*, not a *time zone*. If you are in Oslo, you are in a time zone identified as `Europe/Oslo` that is currently observing `CET`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question experts in English, as a language, can answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is exceptionally rare to encounter designations like *Europe/Oslo* in everyday usage in any English-speaking country I'm familiar with. Local time is indicated by common names, nicknames, abbreviations, or in reference to a locale. Thus, you could write an invitation to a luncheon beginning at noon *Central European Time*, *Central European Standard Time*, *CET*, *Oslo time*, *Norway time*, and so on— but not *noon Europe/Oslo*.

The latter form makes its appearance most often in computing, specifically the IANA's [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) (also known as the zoneinfo database) whence it comes. This database matches time locales like *Asia/Hong_Kong* or *Pacific/Honolulu* to strings matching the [POSIX standard](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1003.1-2008.html) for expressing date and time conversions from UTC.

[IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix-posix/), for one, refers to the newer format as the **Olson time zone** format, in contrast with the older POSIX time zone format. Arthur David Olson of the US National Institutes of Health was the original developer of the tz database, in turn incorporating information originally compiled by a company called Astro Communications Services, which published city timezone data for use by astrologers. In any case, Olson maintained it for so long he became identified with it, and you'll find many references to the *Olson database* in older materials and on Usenet. It is falling out of popularity, but at this writing, there are 428 results on a StackOverflow search on [Olson time](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=olson%20time).

The tz database does not use designations like *West Africa Time* or *Australian Central Daylight Time*, so if the audience is very familiar with the database, you might be able to refer to the *tzdata time zone* or *zoneinfo time zone* in the same way.

Within specific implementations, you should use the standard terminology, however. So although the tz database itself calls that column the timezone *name*, on Microsoft Azure it is the *[time-zone ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt643208.aspx)* and the *name* is a different display string incorporating the offset. In Java, *Europe/Oslo* is your *[zone ID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/timezones.html)*. iCalendar calls it the *[timezone identifier](https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-2-19-time-zone-identifier.html)*.

Comment: Rare indeed. The usecase here is for giving the user a bunch of information about "now", that includes timezone information. Timezone identifier or the fact that CET is what time the timezone observe is what I am looking for. Still don't know how to write it down tho..

Comment: @xeor I gave you possible names for Europe/Oslo: *Olson time zone* or *tzdata time zone* or *zoneinfo time zone*. Because it's not in common usage, it doesn't have a common name. It's not very clear what exactly you are looking for in an answer.